# magento2.4 accordian with plus minus icon

Tags: magento2.4, accordion

**I am creating an FAQ page as a CMS page and want to use the native Magento accordian function however I also want each faq to have a plus minus to indicate it can be open/closed.**

> **I know the accordian code is like below:**

```
<div id="accordion" data-mage-init='{
    "accordion":{
        "active": [1, 2],
        "collapsible": true,
        "openedState": "active",
        "multipleCollapsible": true
    }}'>
<div data-role="collapsible">
    <div data-role="trigger">
        <h4>Title 1</h4>
    </div>
</div>
<div data-role="content">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</div>

<div data-role="collapsible">
    <div data-role="trigger">
        <h4>Title 2</h4>
    </div>
</div>
<div data-role="content"> It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>

<div data-role="collapsible">
    <div data-role="trigger">
        <h4>Title 3</h4>
    </div>
</div>
<div data-role="content">Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old.</div>
```

> **I found a document about adding a plus minus to a collapsable div but not sure how to use it with the accordion() function?**

```
Initialize the collapsible with the icons option specified:
$("#element").collapsible({ icons: {"header": "plus", "activeHeader": "minus"}});
```

***How to do it ?***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just initialize your accordion widget as follows

```
<div id="accordion" data-mage-init='{
    "accordion":{
        "active": [1, 2],
        "collapsible": true,
        "openedState": "active",
        "multipleCollapsible": true,
        "icons": {"header": "plus", "activeHeader": "minus"}
    }}'>
```

This will add a span `<span class="plus" data-role="icons"></span>` to your collapsible element

Magento accordion widget is an extension of the Magento Tabs widget with some additional options

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/javascript-dev-guide/widgets/widget_accordion.html#accordion_options

Magento Tabs widget uses the Magento collapsible widget

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/javascript-dev-guide/widgets/widget_tabs.html#fedg_tabs_options-icons

Answer (score 1):

No need to do any thing by js/ jQuery. You can only just use css as below.

```
#accordion h4:after {
    content: '\002D';
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
}

#accordion .active h4:after {
    content: '\002B';
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: That works, but "display: inline-block;" and "float" should not be used together.